# Setting up 301 redirects using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to set up 301 redirects for a site which has been restructured.

What I currently have is along the lines of:

```
 Redirect 301 /old-page$ /new-page
 Redirect 301 /old-page/subpage /different-page
```

The second redirect works fine, but the first doesn't. If I remove the $, the second redirect will return

```
  /new-page/subpage
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I don't know enough about redirects to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use regex in your first rule by placing `$` but issue is that `Redirect` directive doesn't support regex. You should use `RedirectMatch` like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-page/?$ /new-page
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-page/subpage /different-page
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Added code 301 to the R (redirect) modifier

```
RewriteRule ^/old-page/(.*) /different-page/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is that what u need?